# Add and remove observer from multiple AVPlayerItem on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayerlayer, avplayeritem

i am trying to make a table view that plays multiple videos with `AVPlayer` and `AVPlayerItem` and i needed to addObserver to each `AVPlayerItem` so i can keep track of playbackLikelyToKeepUp property

what i tried and failed is adding the observer after setting the `AVPlayerItem` and removing it in the `deinit` of the `UITableViewCell` but since the cells never gets deallocated but gets dequeued so this won't work and i will get this error

```
An instance 0x14eedebc0 of class AVPlayerItem was 
deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it.
```

After searching I came up with this

- I should not add or remove observers on `UITableViewCell` but i had to because the player item is made in the cell subclass
- The best way to handle observer is within 'UITableViewDelegate' methods
- Adding in `willDisplayCell` and removing in `didEndDisplayingCell`

but even that does not work in my case because `AVPlayerItem` takes time to be initialized

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.setUpPLayer()
        return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = cell as! TableViewCell
        if cell.Player == nil {
            self.addObserversToCell(cell)
        }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = cell as! TableViewCell
        self.removeMyObserversFromCell(cell)
}
```

so the observer won't be add in the `willDisplayCell` but removing the observer will be called and will cause runtime error with

```
'Cannot remove an observer <AVFPlayer.TableViewCell 0x13cf1e9b0> for
the key path "playbackLikelyToKeepUp"  
<AVPlayerItem0x13cf31860> because it is not registered as an observer.'
```

if anyone knows how to achieve this , I would be happy to know ? thanks

Comment: What about subclassing `AVPlayerItem` and do add/remove observer thing in it?

Comment: Looks Interesting , i'll try it

Comment: Awesome works very well , Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the best solution that ever worked for me is to subclass the `AVPlayerItem` and use protocol to delegate back to any class that conforms to `AMPlayerItemDelegate`

here is how i did it

```
protocol AMPlayerItemDelegate {
    func playbackLikelyToKeepUp()
}

class AMPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem {

   var delegate : MyPlayerItemDelegate?

   init(URL: NSURL) {
       super.init(asset: AVAsset(URL: URL) , automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys:[])
       self.addMyObservers()
   }

   deinit {
       self.removeMyObservers()
   }

   func addMyObservers() {
       print("Adding")
       self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackLikelyToKeepUp", options: [.New], context: nil)
   }

   func removeMyObservers() {
       print("Removing")
       self.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackLikelyToKeepUp", context: nil)
   }

   override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
       if keyPath == "playbackLikelyToKeepUp" {
           self.delegate?.playbackLikelyToKeepUp()
       }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to override 'prepareForReuse' function in your UITableViewCell subclass, and remove observer in that place.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    //remove observer here...
}
```

Comment: yes, but that would mean that the observers will hang around until the cell is ready for reuse. This could be a problem if there's a large number of cells.