# Adding a kvc observer to a dynamic reusable cell

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am trying to add an observer to my reusable cell, and the problem is that it adds multiple observers. So I am wondering if there is any way around it because I really need this observer.

```
var player: AVPlayer?

var post: Post? {
    didSet {
      updateView()
    }
}
```

Pretty much post is an array of videos and this gets called every time a post is set as a row on the table view.

This is why I was not able to add the observer in this method because it would be setting multiple observers.

```
func updateView() {
    if let videoUrlString = post?.videoURL {
        let videoUrl = URL(string: videoUrlString)
        player = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl!)
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame = postVideoView.frame
        playerLayer.frame.size.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        self.postVideoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        player?.play()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player?.currentItem, queue: nil, using: { (_) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.player?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
                self.player?.play()
            }
        })
}

    self.updateLike(post: self.post!)
}
```

So then i tried setting it in the awakeFromNib() method.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges", options: .new, context: nil)
}
```

But it wasn't working because the player hadn't been completely initialized yet.

This is my observer function:

```
 override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges" {
        if let duration = player?.currentItem?.duration {
            let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)

            let secondsText = Int(seconds) % 60
            let minutesText = String(format: "%02d", Int(seconds) / 60)
            videoLengthLabel.text = "\(minutesText):\(secondsText)"
        }
    }
}
```

How i remove the observer:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "videoPostCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
    cell.playerLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    cell.player?.pause()
    cell.player?.isMuted = true
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.player?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem, If you have problem to remove observer then you can manage it in below delegate method `UITableView`.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let cell = cell as? CustomCell {
        // Remove your observer here
        // Stop Play Video
    }
}
```

And keep your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as it is. Mean create observer or ETC.

Otherwise below link will be helpful in your case.

1) [Add and remove observer from multiple AVPlayerItem on UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36632104/add-and-remove-observer-from-multiple-avplayeritem-on-uitableviewcell)

2) [Play video on UITableViewCell when it is completely visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825994/play-video-on-uitableviewcell-when-it-is-completely-visible)

3) [Embedding videos in a tableview cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33702490/embedding-videos-in-a-tableview-cell)

Comment: So where should i add the observer?

Comment: You can add observer in cellForRowAtIndexPath and it will be removed in didEndDisplayingCell

Comment: I am now getting a different error that reads this:

An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled.

Is this because I am adding the observer UITableViewDelegate method and handling it inside the TableViewCell?

If so how can i fix this?

Comment: Can you write how you are removing observer ? Normally this issue happens when the registered observer deallocates and a KVO event triggers after that. For fixing you need to remove all observers before your object is going to be deallocated.

Comment: Remove NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player?.currentItem, queue: nil, using: { (_) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.player?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
                self.player?.play()
            }
        })  

And Try

Comment: In didEndDisplaying  method change   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "videoPostCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
to     let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell and Put your calleForRowIndexPath Method code

Comment: I'm assuming you're saying just change the didEndDisplaying method and leave the cellForRowAt method the same. I did that and it gave me the same error